# VIM Hotkey Combo: ALT + Left + Left

Tags: bash, vim

**Question: How do I get VIM do move th ecursor to the beginning of line with a CUSTOM key combo?**

> I know there is a default, but I really love doing `alt + left left`, and `alt + right right` for beginning/end of line cursor.

I have searched the web a bit and tried figuring it out here:

- `$ vim`, `:help key-notation`

**2: This is what I came up with**

**.vimrc**

`imap <A-Left><A-Left> <esc>$i<right>
imap <A-Right><A-Right> <esc>0i`

(Just insert mode is fine)

This does not work though, I understood `<A or M` represents ALT, and `Left` represents Left, from the `man` document.

**Could anyone point me in the right direction?**

I'll toss this in there also, is this possible to do with `/bin/bash`? :)

Comment: Wouldn't hitting `0` be easier?

Comment: First, replace `:imap` by `:inoremap`, it may change the behaviour. And your mappings seem to be swapped (`<A-Left>` <==> `<A-Right>`).

Comment: Just for conciseness, you can replace `<esc>$i<right>` by `<esc>A`

Comment: The ALT modifier won't work if you don't tell your terminal emulator to use it as META. How to do this depends on your terminal emulator. But that's a pointless endeavour; just use `0` in normal mode and `<Home>` in insert mode.

Comment: I dont think this can be done as @romainl said. Using Bash, and Terminator. Oh well. I am not a 100% vim'er,  just want all my  hotkeys the same :P